# How to change font size of UITextView in collectionViewCells at one time?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

**

> I'm trying to change font size of textView inside collectionViewCell ,
> it works and font size change, but not chnage in all cells , the first
> cell not change until swipe all cells and return to it , so how i can
> make textView change in collectionView cell , once i change font size
> from slider pop dialoge .

**

Comment: Can you shows us your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change font size of your UITextView what is inside UICollectionViewCell in function cellForItemAt :

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```